# Angular project compile failed - Module not found

Tags: angular, npm

I am trying to run an Angular project but it's failed. When trying to run "ng serve --open" in my project, I've met these infos:

```
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

Date: 2018-07-29T18:24:22.347Z
Hash: a1b425038571039765db
Time: 16813ms
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 32.8 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 227 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 5.22 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 15.6 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 6.93 MB [initial] [rendered]

WARNING in ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js
113:11-32 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/lib/BufferUtil.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'bufferutil' in 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\chat-app\client\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\lib'

WARNING in ./node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/lib/Validation.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'utf-8-validate' in 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\chat-app\client\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\lib'

ERROR in ./node_modules/base64id/lib/base64id.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\chat-app\client\node_modules\base64id\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/lib/Sender.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\chat-app\client\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocketServer.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\chat-app\client\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\chat-app\client\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\chat-app\client\node_modules\socket.io\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/engine.io.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\chat-app\client\node_modules\engine.io\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\chat-app\client\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocketServer.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\chat-app\client\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\chat-app\client\node_modules\socket.io\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\chat-app\client\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mime-types/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\chat-app\client\node_modules\mime-types'
ERROR in ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\chat-app\client\node_modules\socket.io\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'uws' in 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\chat-app\client\node_modules\engine.io\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/transports/polling.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\chat-app\client\node_modules\engine.io\lib\transports'
ERROR in ./node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/lib/PerMessageDeflate.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\chat-app\client\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\lib'
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

However when I manually get into those files in node_modules, I do see those symbols. Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.1",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^6.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "socket.io": "^2.1.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.7.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
}
```

Are these errors related to SocketIO package? I tried to remove node_modules folder and install again, but still doesn't work. How can I fix this error? Thanks!

Comment: Hi!. did you find a solution? I am in just the same trouble. I tried everything... I even tried understanding how what I tried works. I'm a bit depressed... any clue? (I will post my details soon)

Comment: @Leo128 Hi. Since this issue is months ago, I couldn't remember exactly how I get around with it. What I can remember is it has nothing to do with my setups. Turned out it was some import logic or code logic errors. So do go through your code carefully! Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

I switched from npm to yarn, it works much better and the switch is not very hard to do. I did it by just typing "yarn" on the command line, but you better google a bit, and remember that it is not hard.

Comment: thank you for support.

actually I found a workaroud which does not involve replacing npm with yarn. Yet, I hold a copy of the source as it built like 10 days ago, and it does not build anymore... it indirectly has to do with 'socket.io' when it is included in my Angular 7 application. The same 'socket.io' is also working in a "blind" node.js project without angular.
Now I am using socket.io in the node.js-only part and socket.io-client in the angular 7 app, sharing only some interfaces between the two... and they both work.

I will sure take yarn into consideration soon. thanks again